# Basic Theremin: analogWrite() and tone() commands on the same pin for Arduino theremin

Tags: arduino

I was trying to build a basic theremin with my Arduino for didactic purpose.
My idea was reading a potentiometer for the volume and a photoresistor for the pitch.

My code right now is:

```
 int piezoPin = 5;
 int sensorPin = 1;
 int potPin = 2;

 int sogliaMinima = 20;
 int sogliaMassima = 160;

 void setup () {
   pinMode (piezoPin, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin (9600);
 }

 void loop () {
  // first block of code working
  int potLevel = analogRead (potPin);
  int levelVolume = map (potLevel, 0, 1022, 0, 170);
  analogWrite (piezoPin, levelVolume);


  // second block of code working
  int sensorValue = analogRead (sensorPin);
  int pitchLevel = map (sensorValue, sogliaMinima, sogliaMassima, 100, 1000);
  tone (piezoPin, pitchLevel);
 }
```

This is not working, and it's a software issue not a circuit mistake. Both first block and second block are working if commenting one of them, but don't work together. So my question is: can I use tone() and analogWrite on the same pin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You can't use both functions on the same pin. The two functions analogWrite and tone both attempt to control the pin with a PWM signal. Doing both in sequence changes their defaults. For analogWrite, the tone is 490Hz.

Comment: Thx @jdh, I suspected it but the description of the tone () method wasn't very clear for me :)  If you have any suggestion of how to implement both functions (volume and pitch) with two basic analog sensors, it would be very appreciated. Thx anyway!

Comment: BTW: I didn't mention something important, but maybe you can point me in the right direction. I did a test: instead of reading by the Arduino the voltage setted by the pot and using it to PWM the piezo, I connected directly the + of the piezo to the output of the potentiometer, and it worked. I thought "I'm powering it using the V  setted by the potentiometer, so it must be right". And it was working. But how it's possible that's working when on the same time I'm PWM it with the analogWrite commanded by the value of the photoresistor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that you are calling noTone() to terminate the tone output.

The tone will continually generated until you explicitly stop it via noTone().

If you are still outputting a tone on your pin, and then decide to do an analogWrite() on that same pin, I don't think you will have much luck.

More info can be found here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone

Comment: @Sr.Richie have you tried moving the analogWrite() to a different pin?

Comment: Ok, that way works, but I keep thinking that's basically not okay :(  If both tone() and analogWrite() are outputting PWM, that means that if I connect the piezo to both the pins that are PWM, the voltage/signals arriving to the sensors are mixed up....What do you think? Sorry but I'm obviously not an electronic expert :)

Comment: @Sr.Richie There should not be any issue with that approach... As you undoubtedly know, you are very close to the hardware, so your programming style is going to be quite a bit different than, say, if you were writing Actionscript.  The Arduino has limits, and it is very likely you will do something to hit those limits. :)

Comment: @Sr.Richie To answer the second part of your comment, I don't see why the sensor signals would be messed up?  The piezo buzzer was the on the same pin, so, why would you have issues?

Comment: because I'm feeding the piezo with the pot to set the volume, but at the same time I'm PWM it to set the pitch.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7480/discussion-between-jonathan-and-sr-richie)